# UIButton in objective c

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IBOutlet in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715670/iboutlet-in-objective-c)

what is the function of this line

```
IBOutlet UIButton *storeNumber;
```

Comment: Does the same thing as your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

It's creating an outlet for interface builder. You are able to connect this UIButton property with a UIButton in IB.

Apple Documentation says:

> **IBOutlet** 
>   Identifier used to qualify an instance-variable
>   declaration so that Interface Builder
>   can synchronize the display and
>   connection of outlets with Xcode.
>   Insert this identifier immediately
>   before the variable type in any
>   variable declarations. For examples,
>   including how to use it with the
>   @property syntax, see “Xcode
>   Integration”.