# UIButton in objective c

Tags: objective-c

what is the function of UIButton in " UIButton *storenumber;

Comment: Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Comment: sorry friend,  but you are asking this question for the third time..duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715939/uibutton-in-objective-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715670/iboutlet-in-objective-c

Comment: You are creating a pointer named storeNumber of type UIButton ...This is my answer from what I understood from the question..He is really having some trouble understanding variables and datatypes :(

Comment: @dks1725 ijust want to know that is UIButton some kind of datatype

Comment: I have voted up on this to give him his points back, but only because I think he actually needs to know. In return, I would like to know how much my answer helped.

Comment: @Joe: and @Justin: even if it was a _valid_ question, it's already been answered _twice_ today, as Krishnabhadra pointed out well before you posted.

Comment: @Josh Caswell - yes you are correct, close vote time.

Comment: @Josh I'm sorry, I didn't know that those were answered yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

`UIButton *` is the type of the pointer. `storenumber` is a variable that points to an instance of the UIButton class.

Answer (score -2):

As Caleb said, it is a pointer type. This is very useful whenever you have a button in your app, especially because you will need it to release the button in the dealloc method. I have also found that it is useful because you it will let you change the image, size, position, ect. of the button. If you don't know how to use these things, look at the examples below.

```
- (void) dealloc {
   [someButton release];
}
```

This will release the button, thereby allowing giving you more memory to work with. The following examples are used quite often by programmers.

```
[someButton setHidden:(BOOL)];
[someBuuton setImage:(UIImage*) forState:(UIControlState)];
[someButton setFrame:(CGRect)];
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Why was this voted down? I tried to give some good detail in the basic use of a UIButton outlet, so user714927 could understand it better.

Comment: Your answere is more related to the functionality of the UIButton class, and does not address the question above, which is a syntax/langauge format question that has been successfully answered by @Caleb